# LLVM Comparing arguments of two functions

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Suppose I have:

```
foo(int a, int b){
  bar(a)
}
```

how would I check if argument `a` in `bar` is the same as argument `a` in `foo` in the llvm IR(*.ll file) I get something this:

`test.ll`:

```
 18 ; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
 19 define i32 @foo(i32 %a, i32 %b) #0 {
 20 entry:
 21   %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
 22   %b.addr = alloca i32, align 4
 23   %f = alloca i32, align 4
 24   store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
 25   store i32 %b, i32* %b.addr, align 4
 26   %0 = load i32, i32* %a.addr, align 4
 27   %call = call i32 @baz(i32 %0)
 28   store i32 %call, i32* %f, align 4
 29   %1 = load i32, i32* %f, align 4
 30   ret i32 %1
 31 }
 32
```

Comment: What does "same" mean?

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to tell that the `a` in `bar(a)` is a parameter of `foo`. I am trying to decipher  whether or not the parameters of `bar` are directly passed in from the parent function call, namely `foo`.

Comment: Is *'a'* parameter or is an *'effectively const'* parameter or just a *'not yet reassigned'* parameter?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean but `a` is just a parameter

Comment: `foo(int a) { a=2; b(a); }` - what should this report?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, lets say in this scenario `foo(int a) { a=2; b(a); }` that we do equate the `a` in `b(a)` to the `a` in `foo(int a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are only asking if the same variable is passed on to bar or not.

to check that while running on function

```
 runOnFunction(Function &F)
 {
    Function::ArgumentListType &sArgs = F.getArgumentList();
    Function::ArgumentListType::iterator psArg = sArgs.begin();
    Function::ArgumentListType::iterator psEndArg = sArgs.end();

    /* this will iterate through function arguments */
    for ( ;psArg != psEndArg; ++psArg)
    {
        /* iterate argument uses */
        Argument::user_iterator psUSe = psArg->user_begin();
        Argument::user_iterator psUSeEnd = psArg->user_end();
        for (;psUSe != psUSeEnd ; ++psUSe)
        {
            /* check if it is call to bar or not */
            if (CallInst* psCall = dyn_cast<CallInst>(*psUSe))
            //if (const CallInst* psInst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(*psUSe))
            {
               if(psCall->getCalledFunction()->getName().startswith("bar") 
                { // hurray found it, do something
                }
            }    

         }
     }
  }
```

above code will check if function argument is diractly passed to another function call.